# In C# for a discord bot, is it possible to Give every command his own file

Tags: c#

I am trying to make my first Discord bot and I was wondering if it is possible to give every command his own file, so it is easier to see where it goes wrong, disable commands one at the time, and it is just less chaotic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you currently have and where is the problem?

Comment: I just want to have a command +help and +delete, and I want them both to be in a different file, instead of everything being in the main file

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible, but you have to be more specific for us to give specific answers.

Comment: What do you want to know? I just want every command to have his own file.

Comment: What API are you using? How does your code look like? Just give us information to work with. Like this it's just guess work.

Answer (score 0):

Giving every command its on file would be bad practice. You say it'd be less chaotic but you'd be making it more chaotic.

If you are wanting to separate your commands for debugging purposes then I could suggest an option which would be put all commands of the same permission level in the same file. So if you say have three commands, lets call them A B and C; in which C requires you to be an admin to the bot. You could do something along the lines of storing command A and B in the same file and because you have command C needing elevated permissions you can then put that in a file labelled something along the lines of adminCommands.

This would separate your commands a little more while still keeping it organised and following the Separation of concerns.